# Oracle imp / exp

Tags: oracle, import, export

After a full Oracle export, are the views preserved when I import the dump file ?

The db version is 11g .

The utilities are **imp** / **exp** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views are transferred, but not optimized. It means that you have the views (DDL is available), but they are not populated.
You can see in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004890) that in Full mode User views it says 'Yes'